# Failed to copy or paste from the RDP session of windows server

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2

We was apply few security patches on windows server. After that I am not able to copy or paste any data on windows machine using the RDP session. I am not sure what was changed. How can I troubleshoot on the issue or what are the possible reasons which are causing the same?

Answer (score 0):

Making two different files: **temp**.txt on your windows machine, and **temp1**.txt on your server.

Use Ctrl + C combination to copy both files and see if you can copy either of them to the other end after doing this:

Going to the server, open **Task Manager**, kill the **rdpclip.exe** process.

Click **Start**, search for "**rdpclip.exe**", open it.